# Adding item to the List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I am probably doing something silly but cannot find out what. I am trying to modify simple membership functionality in ASP.NET MVC 4. I have slightly modified a RegisterModel coming with the template, and added a list of categories to it like so:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    ...

    public List<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the account controller I'm trying to add an item to this list but get "`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`" error:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    RegisterModel rm = new RegisterModel();

    //SelectListItem guestCategory = new SelectListItem();
    //guestCategory.Value = null;
    //guestCategory.Text = "Guest";

    rm.Categories.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = null, Text = "Guest" });
...
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Categories is never being constructed?

Comment: `rm.Categories` is `null`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you just need to do this before adding items to list , because when you add items its not get instantiated that why its giving error

```
rm.Categories = new List<SelectListItem>();
```

that means in this method do like this

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    RegisterModel rm = new RegisterModel();

    rm.Categories = new List<SelectListItem>();//added line 

    rm.Categories.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = null, Text = "Guest" });
...
```

or

you can do same thing in constructor of `RegisterModel` .

```
public class RegisterModel
{
  public RegisterModel
  {
    Categories = new List<SelectListItem>();//added line 
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

In your class constructor initialize the list

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    RegisterModel()
    {
     Categories  = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
......
```

Since you are using an **[auto-implemented property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)** `{get;set;}` you have to initialize it in the constructor. If you don't want to do in the Constructor then you can do:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    ...
    private List<SelectListItem> _Categories = new List<SelectListItem>();

    private List<SelectListItem> Categories
    {
        get { return _Categories; }
        set { _Categories = value; }
    }
}
```

You can also initialize the List with the object, before using it.

```
RegisterModel rm = new RegisterModel();
r.Categories = new List<SelectListItem>(); // like that
rm.Categories.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = null, Text = "Guest" });
```

But **its better if you initialize the list in constructor or through a private field** *(if not using auto-implemented property)*, Because then you don't have to initialize a property of the object of Class `RegisterModel`, with each object creation.

Answer (score 5):

You never initialized `Categories` to anything. It is `null`.

Initialize it to an empty list to avoid the error, preferably in the constructor:

```
Categories = new List<SelectListItem>();
```